# SQL Need answer and explanation for the below query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT
    users.name,
    COUNT(*) as count
FROM
    users
    LEFT JOIN friends ON users.id = friends.user1
    OR users.id = friends.user2
WHERE
    users.sex = 'f'
GROUP BY
    users.id,
    users.name;
```

Comment: Do you have an actual question?

Comment: it show how many friends a  user has that are female

Answer (score 1):

Looks like homework, but here goes

Show the name and count the number times a female user is a first or second friend